# bordering a sheet

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to border a sheet 10 mm from each side, how should i do this? i tried page border but i didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2):

You may like the drawing method:

1. Click the Drawing toolbar button on the Standard toolbar, or point to Toolbars on the View menu, and then click Drawing.
2. Click Line on the Drawing toolbar.
   Place the pointer where you want the line to start. The mouse pointer is a crosshair (+).
3. Click and hold the mouse button, and drag the line to the length you want.

Comment: it is a toolbar where you may see lines, brush and paintings…. or just click View and choose Drawing.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what happened with page border, but there is an option (literally an options link on the page border tab in the borders and shading dialog box) to change the borders distance from the edge of page or text.
Hope this helps.

[image: borders dialog box]